# Ubuntu 18.04 Pulse secure won't start

Tags: 18.04

I am trying to understand why Pulse secure installed via Debian package is not starting at all.
I am able see it in the GUI menu, when clicked the Menu disappears and now the application should start, but it doesn't.

In terminal with Sudo access I type `pulse` and hit <kbd>enter</kbd>, but this doesn't execute it.

```
root@user:/home/user# pulse 
Command 'pulse' not found, did you mean: 
  command 'apulse' from deb apulse 
Try: apt install <deb name>
```

List of Applications Shows a different name:

```
root@user:/home/user# ls -lh /usr/share/applications | grep pulse
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  285 Aug 29  2017 pulseUi.desktop
```

What's confusing me is while removing this package I am able to see this in terminal.

```
user@user:~$  sudo apt remove pulse
pulse                        pulseaudio                   pulseaudio-module-bluetooth  pulseaudio-utils
```

Additional Information:

```
uname -a
Linux user 4.15.0-22-generic #24-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 16 12:15:17 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Appreciate your time already in reading the details above.

Answer (score 20):

Executing the command inside the `pulseUi.desktop` file. I get the following error:

> /usr/local/pulse/pulseUi:error while loading shared libraries: libwebkitgtk-1.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

The error is caused by the missing library libwebkitgtk-1.0.so.0.  I solved the problem by installing the following package

`sudo apt-get install libwebkitgtk-1.0`

Update: On another Ubuntu 18.04 workstation, I have to install the `libgnome-keyring0` as well.

The general solution is to execute the executable file, e.g. `/usr/local/pulse/pulseUi`. Then install all the missing libraries that are reported in the error messages.

Comment: This seemed to work for me, now I can open the application

Comment: For me this almost worked but, perhaps due to an older version of the installer, I had to use "sudo apt-get install libwebkitgtk-1.0:i386" .

Answer (score 9):

In the Ubuntu Version 18.04, You could install Pulse Secure, post download, using the below command:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i /home/{user}/Downloads/ps-pulse-linux-9.0r2.0-b819-ubuntu-debian-64-bit-installer.deb
```

Followed by installing the below required dependencies:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libwebkitgtk-1.0.0
$ sudo apt-get install libproxy1-plugin-webkit
$ sudo apt-get install libgnome-keyring0
```

Comment: Where can I download the deb file from? I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: You could download it from: https://www.pulsesecure.net/trynow/client-download/. You'll have to register yourself. You'd get the download link via an email at your registered email ID.